# Jenkins Build Setup

Tags: jenkins

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am trying to setup Jenkins to build my ros hydro packages.  I have yet to find any useful documentation on integrating ROS with Jenkins.  Can someone point me in the correct directions as to how to setup the ROS Environment and run catkin_make on a package?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/150271/jenkins-build-setup/) by [mdedonato](https://answers.ros.org/users/4929/mdedonato/) on ROS Answers with karma: 61 on 2014-04-08

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The [buildfarm](http://wiki.ros.org/buildfarm) documentation describes how to set up a build farm for ROS similar to the current build farm that is run by OSRF.

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2014-04-08

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1